# Printing compiler and linker commands when building C Extension with distutils

Tags: python, c, setuptools, distutils

I'm trying to debug a setup.py file for a package that builds a C extension with

```
from distutils.core import Extension
ext = Extension(...
```

I'd like to see what compiler / linker commands are actually getting executed.  How do I print them when running

```
pip install -e ./
```

or

```
python setup.py install
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be that it wasn't rebuilding the extension, but rather using a cached version.  If I run

```
python setup.py clean --all
python setup.py develop
```

it rebuilds and shows all the compile/link commands.